# VBScript in HTA - Find next open cell in Excel Column

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have searched around with no avail.  Im new at VB and VBS and cant seem to get this to work. Im looking to search for the next empty cell in A, and enter a value in via objexcel.  This is all contained within an HTA.

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
Sub TallySportsBottle()
Dim oXLApp, wb, ws

'~~> Define xlUp
Const xlUp = -4162


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Gloria Vena\Desktop\new2\Excel\SportsBottleIssuesTally.xlsx")
Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
   lastRowIndex = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
End With

objExcel.Selection.Value = "X"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got most of it. `lastRowIndex` should tell you the last row number that contains data in column A. So you'd need to add a value to the *next* row (`lastRowIndex + 1`).

```
With ws
    lastRowIndex = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    .Cells(lastRowIndex + 1, 1) = "X"
End With
```

and then you can get rid this line from your code:

```
objExcel.Selection.Value = "X"
```